# Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found (Spark 1.6 Windows)

Tags: windows, amazon-s3, apache-spark, windows-10, pyspark

I am trying to access s3 files from local spark context using pySpark.
I keep getting `File "C:\Spark\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 308, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.parquet.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem not found`

I had set `os.environ['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']` and
`os.environ['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']` before I called `df = sqc.read.parquet(input_path)`. I also added these lines:
`hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", os.environ["AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"])
hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", os.environ["AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"])`

I have also tried changing `s3` to `s3n`, `s3a`. Neither worked.

Any idea how to make it work?
I am on Windows 10, pySpark, Spark 1.6.1 built for Hadoop 2.6.0

Answer (score 8):

I'm running pyspark appending the libraries from **hadoop-aws**.

You will need to use **s3n** in your input path. I'm running that from Mac-OS. so I'm not sure if it will work in Windows.

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1
```

Comment: Its helpful for me in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This package declaration works even in spark-shell

> spark-shell --packages org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-aws:2.7.1

and specify in the shell

> sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsAccessKeyId", "xxxxxxxxxxxxx")
>     sc.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3n.awsSecretAccessKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")